# Nontrivial solutions for $|x\rangle$ in the equation $\langle x | M | x \rangle = \langle y | x \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for help in finding solutions for $| x \rangle$ in the following equation:
$$
\langle x | M | x \rangle = \langle y | x \rangle.
$$
The vectors $| x \rangle$ and $|y \rangle$ are in general complex-valued vectors. In my notation (Dirac notation) $| x \rangle$ stands for the complex transpose of $\langle x |$.

As posed, we are given $M$ and $| y \rangle$. $M$ (a real matrix in this case) can be broken into its symmetric and antisymmetric parts, $M = A + S$. Since $\langle x | A | x \rangle = 0$, we have
$$
\langle x | S | x \rangle = \langle y | x \rangle.
$$ 
I'm not sure if this helps, but it simplifies the problem a little.

The question is: is there any way to say anything concrete about the solutions $| x \rangle$? I expect that the solutions will be degenerate, and that is okay. However I have never seen an equation like this and it's throwing me for a loop.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Are there any information on $M$? Is it invertible?

Comment: @Levent, we may suppose $M$ is invertible.

Comment: I mean, there is always an obvious solution $\mid x\rangle = (M^{-1})^T\mid y\rangle$ but I do not know what you exactly want.

Comment: @Levent, thank you, that is a solution. And yet somehow that solution is wrong (for the more general problem I am trying to solve.) Perhaps there is a problem with how I'm setting things up. I will look into it. Thanks for the insight. When/if I find the issue I will edit this page accordingly.